# Is it good practice to yield from within a context manager?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

I recently wrote a method which returned a sequence of open files; in other words, something like this:

```
# this is very much simplified, of course
# the actual code returns file-like objects, not necessarily files
def _iterdir(self, *path):
    dr = os.path.join(*path)
    paths = imap(lambda fn: os.path.join(dr, fn), os.listdir(dr))

    return imap(open, paths)
```

Syntactically, I do *not* expect to have to close the resulting objects if I do something like:

```
for f in _iterdir('/', 'usr'):
    make_unicorns_from(f)
    # ! f.close()
```

As a result, I decided to wrap `_iterdir` in a context manager:

```
def iterdir(self, *path):
    it = self._iterdir(*path)

    while 1:
        with it.next() as f:
            yield f
```

This appears to be working correctly.

What I'm interested in is whether doing this is good practice.  Will I run into any issues following this pattern (perhaps if exceptions are thrown)?

Comment: Looks fine, I did a quick check with a custom context manager and `__exit__` was getting called fine even when an exception occurred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems I see. One is that if you try to use more than one file at a time, things break:

```
list(iterdir('/', 'usr')) # Doesn't work; they're all closed.
```

The second is unlikely to happen in CPython, but if you have a reference cycle, or if your code is ever run on a different Python implementation, the problem can manifest.

If an exception happens in `make_unicorns_from(f)`:

```
for f in iterdir('/', 'usr'):
    make_unicorns_from(f) # Uh oh, not enough biomass.
```

The file you were using won't be closed until the generator is garbage-collected. At that point, the generator's `close` method will be called, throwing a `GeneratorExit` exception at the point of the last `yield`, and the exception will cause the context manager to close the file.

With CPython's reference counting, this usually happens immediately. However, on a non-reference-counted implementation or in the presence of a reference cycle, the generator might not be collected until a cycle-detecting GC pass is run. This could take a while.

---

My gut says to leave closing the files to the caller. You can do

```
for f in _iterdir('/', 'usr'):
    with f:
        make_unicorns_from(f)
```

and they'll all be closed promptly, even without a `with` in the generator, and even if an exception is thrown. I don't know whether or not this is actually a better idea than having the generator take charge of closing the files.

Comment: The first issue you mention looks like something that would be incredibly difficult to debug if you forgot the cause!  I think for that reason alone this pattern is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, and somewhat tangentially, thanks for making clear that you can safely nest `with` statements (as in, apply the context manage to an already opened file).  I wasn't aware that that was possible.

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of `with` involves unifying opening and closing with exception safety and explicit lifetimes. Your abstraction removes some of that, but not all.

Here's a totally-simplified example:

```
def with_open():
    with open(...) as f:
        yield f
```

Consider an exception in its usage:

```
for _ in with_open():
    raise NotImplementedError
```

This will not terminate the loop, and so the file will be left open. Possibly forever.

Consider incomplete, non-exception based exits, too:

```
for _ in with_open():
    break

for _ in with_open():
    return

next(with_open())
```

---

One option is to return a context manager itself, so that you can do:

```
def with_open():
    yield partial(open, ...)

for filecontext in with_open():
    with filecontext() as f:
        break
```

Another, more direct solution, would be to define the function as

```
from contextlib import closing

def with_open(self, *path):
    def inner():
        for file in self._iterdir(*path):
            with file:
                yield file

    return closing(inner())
```

and use it as

```
with iterdir() as files:
    for file in files:
        ...
```

This guarantees closure without having to move the opening of files to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I wasn't aware that breaking or returning wouldn't clean up the manager; that's a serious issue.